# OnClick Event Not Firing on Button Click ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, event-handling

I have an asp:Button that is in a JavaScript dialog window. It has an OnClick event called DialogWindowButton_Click as you can see in the code below. The event is not firing and I have put breakpoints in the C# file and it is not even entering the function. I'm not sure why and have looked at other forum posts to try to figure this out. I have 1) deleted the button and recreated the button and OnClick event themselves (this didn't work), and 2) added CausesValidation="False" to the asp:Button tag. Neither avenue has worked. What I have is shown below:

```
<div style="margin:auto; width:100px; padding-bottom:15px;">
    <asp:Button ID="DialogWindowButton" runat="server" Text="Save Entry" 
    OnClick="DialogWindowButton_Click" CausesValidation="False"/>
</div>
```

Then in the C# file, I have:

```
    ...
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DialogWindowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogWindowButton_ClickHelper();
        ...
    }

    protected AddressBookEntry DialogWindowButton_ClickHelper()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

I have the correct file for the CodeBehind tag as well as for the Inherits tag. In the C# file you can see that the original OnClick event calls on a helper function defined directly below it, but breakpoints in the top of DialogWindowButton_Click() aren't being reached. There are no build errors either. Could there be something else I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: What is the `CodeBehind` and `Inherits` of aspx page? And does Page_Load is fired when you try to open page?

Comment: Just set a breakpoint on Page_Load and it does indeed fire when expected. The original file is AddressBook.aspx. The CodeBehind is AddressBook.aspx.cs. And Inherits is _321SOS.WebForm1.

Comment: Have you tried set [`UseSubmitBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_Button_UseSubmitBehavior) to false(default is true).

Comment: Yes this worked! Thank you! How did this property enable this to work?

Comment: I have added as an answer with explanation. Please check.

Comment: With this UseSubmitBehavior="false" property, though, the fields that I'm trying to save to the database in the DialogWindowButton_ClickHelper() function are unable to do so I believe. Do you know of a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [`UseSubmitBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_Button_UseSubmitBehavior) to `false` (default is true):

```
 <asp:Button ID="DialogWindowButton" runat="server" Text="Save Entry" 
    UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="DialogWindowButton_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
```

From [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Use the UseSubmitBehavior property to specify whether a Button control
>   uses the client browser's submit mechanism or the ASP.NET postback
>   mechanism. By default the value of this property is true, causing the
>   Button control to use the browser's submit mechanism. If you specify
>   false, the ASP.NET page framework adds client-side script to the page
>   to post the form to the server.

Comment: With this UseSubmitBehavior="false" property, though, the fields that I'm trying to save to the database in the DialogWindowButton_ClickHelper() function are unable to do so I believe. Do you know of a way around this?

Comment: Sorry but i think you have another issue which is not about current question and it is hard to understand from this. You can ask another question with enough detail.

Comment: I've added an answer below that will hopefully help you understand my connection better.

Comment: * understand my question better